# How to express a One-To-Many relationship in Django without using foreignkey in class on the side many-relation?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a project to manage Assets in company. Asset is the core of project. I need to express One-To-Many relationship and Many-To-Many with Assets and the only way I know that:

```
class List(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Asset(models.Model):
     list = models.ForeignKey(List)
```

I don't think that a good way because I have more classs like List in the project and if I do that, Asset will be have too much attributes are not necessary, when I have a new Asset I need to declare the attribute "list" - that impossible if that list doesn't exist (new list in future). Is there any way? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you explain clearly what you try to do because I don;t really understand what you want right now